# Fraying violin A -string

Tags: strings, violin

My violin's A-string is fraying (unravelling a bit) near the bridge. Right now, my playing is a little squeaky there but nothing very noticeable. Will this get worse or is it fine to leave the string like this? Is there a string which I can buy which is hard to fray? And how to avoid the fraying of strings in general?

Comment: Ask anyone who's had a string snap  what happened to their left-hand fingers as a result -- you'll replace that string in an instant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get strings that come with a tiny moveable hollow tube that sits on the bridge and allows the string to move as it needs through it, thus helping prevent fraying.  I would recommend changing your string sooner rather than later as it is at risk of breaking.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the string is just badly manufactured... this happens sometimes (most often in cheaper strings, but I've also had a few faulty ones where the price should have suggested better quality).

Likely though, the bridge at least contributes a bit as well. The grooves in the bridge should be filed wide and round enough to allow the string to slip a little bit without getting damaged. Might be a good idea to ask a luthier.

In the meanwhile, when you put on a new string yourself (which you certainly should do before any performance!) you can do a little bit against new damage by dry-lubricating the groove with some graphite from a pencil.

Comment: No, it's a Dominant string, they have worked well with me in the past

Comment: As I said, branding doesn't guarantee that every single string is perfectly ok.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, I would say that no matter how correctly the violin is set up, wound strings will eventually fray and break, usually at the bridge or nut.  No string lives forever.